# How to get modules list inside particular namespace

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I am trying to get all the modules names inside the particular Namespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get modules with below code

```
$modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();

        $options = array();

        $options[] = array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('-- None --'),
            'value' => ''
        );




        foreach($modules as $key => $value):

        if (strpos($key, '//yournamespacehere') !== FALSE):



            $options[] = array(
               'label' => $key,
               'value' => $key
            );

            endif;

        endforeach;
```